# failed to execute user defined function on spark data frame in Apache Spark stand alone using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF like this

```
case class bodyresults(text:String,code:String)

val bodyudf = udf{ (body: String)  =>
    //Appending body tag explicitly to the xml before parsing  
    val xmlElems = xml.XML.loadString(s"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE body [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]><body>${body}</body>""")
    // extract the code inside the req
    val code = (xmlElems \\ "body" \\"code").text
    val text = (xmlElems \\ "body").text.replace(s"${code}" ,"" )
    bodyresults(text, code)
}
```

I am trying to do convert Body string into code, text strings

CODE: inside the xml elements named code.

TEXT: Everything else.

The column body type is String and the contents looks like this

```
 <p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>
<p>This is my code:</p>
 <pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;
 this.Opacity = trans;
</code></pre>
<p>When I build the application, it gives the following error:</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>I tried using <code>trans</code> and <code>double</code> but then the 
control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project. </p>
,While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?
```

I am trying to use this UDF using the following command

```
val posts5=posts4.withColumn("codetext",bodyudf(col("Body")))
posts5.select("codetext").show()
```

This causes Error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string) => struct<text:string,code:string>)

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 129; The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</body>"
```

But as you can see in the UDF I am appending body tag and closing it.

Note: Whats surprising is that it works fine if execute below command

```
posts5.select("codetext").show(19)
+--------------------+
|            codetext|
+--------------------+
|[Given a  represe...|
|[Is there any sta...|
|[What is the diff...|
|[How do I store b...|
|[If I have a trig...|
|[How do you page ...|
|[Does anyone know...|
|[Does anybody kno...|
|[What are some gu...|
|[There are severa...|
|[I wrote a window...|
|[How do I format ...|
|[One may not alwa... |
|[Are PHP variable...|
|[What's the simpl...|
|[Does anyone know...|
|[I'm looking for ...| 
|[What is the corr...|
|[I was wondering ...|
+--------------------+
```

But if I use any number more than 19 its causing error

```
posts5.select("codetext").show(20)
or
posts5.select("codetext").show()
```

Just in case I am attaching the body string in the 20th row

```
<p>I have a Queue&lt;T&gt; object that I have initialised to a capacity of 2, but obviously that is just the capacity and it keeps expanding as I add items.  Is there already an object that automatically dequeues an item when the limit is reached, or is the best solution to create my own inherited class?</p>,Limit size of Queue<T> in .NET?
```

I can not figure out what is the reason for this error. I can not find relevant information on web so please let me know whats causing error?

EDIT:

I dropped the row 20 because that string is missing the closing tag .
But now the error comes at row 19.

```
posts5.select("codetext").show(18) //18 or below works fine
posts5.select("codetext").show(19) // does not work
```

I have taken string in 19 th row passed it directly to function and its working fine.
But when I pass the entire column to UDF its not working?

Comment: well, it looks like your xml string is malformed. Specifically the string template used to generate `xmlElems`. don't know the class well enough to point to solution, but that's probably where your problem lies. Try debugging that with some simpler dummy text, so it's easier to diagnose. It doesn't even need to be in the udf for the debugging, to make the problem even clearer, and the problem more minimal.

Comment: When I passed the strings directly to function its working fine. I dropped the row 20 because that string is not in a proper XML format because of its missing closing tag</T> .   But still having the same error?